# AVERAGEIFS seems to consider only single value in range

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, average, array-formulas

My AVERAGEIFS formula seems to consider only a single element out of the two that it should theoretically select. In the following case for instance, if I ask what is the average age of Beatles members who said yes, I only get 32, John's age in this case. I insist on having to "manually select" names (use a list).

My formula goes as following:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C1:C9,A1:A9,"yes",B1:B9,{"john","paul","ringo","george"})
```

What am I missing?

Also is there such a thing as STDEVIFS? Because I would like to calculate the standard deviation of the data that meets the criteria in the above formula (once edited of course).

[image]

Comment: Your formula is returning an array of values, some of which are div/0 errors. You need to compensate for that.  pNuts answer is one method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**  Corrected the formula to include "YES" as a criteria:

The following should be entered with **ctrl-shift-enter**

```
=STDEV(IF((A1:A9="YES")*(B1:B9={"john","paul","ringo","george"}),C1:C9))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A9="YES")*(B1:B9={"JOHN","GEORGE","RINGO","PAUL"})*(C1:C9))/SUM(COUNTIFS(A1:A9,"YES",B1:B9,{"JOHN","GEORGE","RINGO","PAUL"}))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! How about stdevifs? Would that be possible in any sort of way?

Answer (score 2):

If you use an array formula similar to Ron's suggestion then you can use exactly the same syntax for both `AVERAGE` and `STDEV`, i.e. this formula for averaging rows which contain yes and a Beatle

`=AVERAGE(IF(A1:A9="Yes",IF(B1:B9={"John","Paul","Ringo","George"},C1:C9)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

replace AVERAGE with STDEV to get standard deviation with the same conditions. You can also use the same syntax for multiple other functions, e.g. `MIN/MAX/MEDIAN/SUM` etc.